# Python 3 memory error processing more than 51 million lines of csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a large (60gb) csv file. This is python 3.6.4 on Windows 10 with 16GB of ram. Right now I am simply attempting to iterate over the lines of a file like so:

```
with open('large_csv.csv') as myfile:
    count = 0
    for line in myfile:
        if count % 1000000 == 0:
            print(count)
        count += 1
```

The issue is that at 51 million lines, python freezes. Throughout this whole process, my memory usage has not changed a bit. After several seconds, it *then* consumes all my system's memory and crashes everything if I don't force cancel it. I don't see why memory should be an issue here.

Something that might be important is that when trying to open the file in EmEditor, I get a pop-up saying "Null characters (00H) contained in the file". Perhaps the file has bad data?

I also tried using pandas to read the csv in chunks, but eventually run out of memory and the program freezes:

```
import pandas as pd
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv('large_csv.csv', chunksize=chunksize):
    print('chunk')
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: The code posted here uses a file buffer, a single string and a single integer and will never use any more memory than a few megabytes at most.

Comment: We'll need precise version info and your OS if this is really all there is to it (with indentation corrected). We process files much larger than this on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried providing all the information I can and added a possible cause of the issue.